# inconsistent vendoring golang

Tags: golang

Попытался поставить несколько пакетов через go get (go-redis, fasthttp и jackc/pgx), предварительно создав проект через jetbrains goland. Goland любезно предложил ввести go mod tidy и go mod vendor,но это не устраняет проблему и проект все так-же не билдится и показывает это же сообщение, даже когда main.go с одной пустой функцией main внутри. Как бороться? Версия go - 1.13.6,  GOROOT = C:\Go, 
GOPATH = C:\Users\User\go

> go: inconsistent vendoring in C:\Go\src\golangProjects\coursework:
>       go.mod requires golangProjects/coursework  but vendor/modules.txt does not include it.
>       run 'go mod tidy; go mod vendor' to sync

Comment: Хотелось бы еще добавить, что jackc/pgx и fasthttp встали нормально, проблема возникла после добавления go-redis и не исчезает даже после его замены на redigo

Answer (score 0):

Решилось переустановкой GoLand и инициализированием с помощью go mod init перед скачиванием библиотек.